# NSURLSessionDownloadTask: How to change the location where tem files are saved

Tags: ios, preload

Under normal circumstances, downloading (video) files will be saved under the location path (.tmp), then move the file (.tmp) to our target folder using the following de;egate method.

But I want to do the downloading and playing, how can I change the file path(location) to the target path(destinationURL) before I download it.

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location
{
    NSError *error;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *destinationFileName = downloadTask.originalRequest.URL.lastPathComponent;
    NSURL *destinationURL = [self.downloadDirURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:destinationFileName];
    if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[destinationURL path]])
    {
        [fileManager removeItemAtURL:destinationURL error:nil];
    }
    BOOL success = [fileManager moveItemAtURL:location toURL:destinationURL error:&error];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> But I want to do the downloading and playing, how can I change the file path(location) to the target path(destinationURL) before I download it

You can't. What you are doing is correct for a download task: download to where it downloads to (which is no concern of yours), and immediately move it to a useful location as soon as the download is complete.

(Note, however, that you do *not* need to download a video file merely in order to play it. You can just start playing the file across the Internet. So perhaps the problem here is that you are downloading in the first place.)

Comment: What I want to achieve is the video preloading function, download video with cocoahttpserver, and then set it to the player's playback source, but if I can't change the path of location, I need to wait until the video download is completed.it is certainly not acceptable

Comment: Then this is not an appropriate use of a download task — as I suggested in my answer.